# java.io.NotSerializableException with custom UserDetails implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I try to secure my Spring Boot app with OAuth2. Everyting works fine to some point. When I try to get access token from `oauth/token` endpoint ath first try I am getting token without problem. When I to try get it again I receive exception for custom `UserDetails` implementation:

```
Failed to deserialize authentication

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.NotSerializableException: Not allowed to deserialize com.example.oauth.user.domain.User
```

User enity:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "uuid")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_users")
public class User implements UserDetails {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "uuid")
  private String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

  @Column(name = "username")
  private String username;

  @Column(name = "password")
  private String password;

  @Column(name = "account_expired")
  private boolean accountExpired;

  @Column(name = "account_locked")
  private boolean accountLocked;

  @Column(name = "credentials_expired")
  private boolean credentialsExpired;

  @Column(name = "enabled")
  private boolean enabled;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "users_authorities",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "authority_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
  private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();

  @Override
  public Collection<Authority> getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return !isAccountExpired();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return !isAccountLocked();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return !isCredentialsExpired();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
  }
}
```

I noticed that when I change in returned value in `UserDetailsServiceImpl` to User from `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails` package it works fine.

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

  private final UserRepository userRepository;

  public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);

// With custom user I get java.ioNotSerializableException 
//    return user;

// With that everything is ok
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),
        user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
  }
}
```

The problem occurs in `JdbcTokenStore` `getAccessToken` method

```
  public OAuth2AccessToken getAccessToken(OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = null;
    String key = this.authenticationKeyGenerator.extractKey(authentication);

    try {
      accessToken = (OAuth2AccessToken)this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(this.selectAccessTokenFromAuthenticationSql, new RowMapper<OAuth2AccessToken>() {
        public OAuth2AccessToken mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
          return JdbcTokenStore.this.deserializeAccessToken(rs.getBytes(2));
        }
      }, new Object[]{key});
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException var5) {
      if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOG.debug("Failed to find access token for authentication " + authentication);
      }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException var6) {
      LOG.error("Could not extract access token for authentication " + authentication, var6);
    }

    if (accessToken != null && !key.equals(this.authenticationKeyGenerator.extractKey(this.readAuthentication(accessToken.getValue())))) {
      this.removeAccessToken(accessToken.getValue());
      this.storeAccessToken(accessToken, authentication);
    }

    return accessToken;
  }
```

I do not really understand why this problem occurs for custom User and works fine for User from spring security package. Did anyone have similar problem before? Of course at the end using sprign user is some kind of workaround but I would like to understand why it does not work this way.

**EDIT:**
Stacktrace

```
2019-11-14 22:49:25.227  WARN 9350 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.o.p.token.store.JdbcTokenStore     : Failed to deserialize authentication

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.NotSerializableException: Not allowed to deserialize com.example.oauth.user.domain.User
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.util.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:66) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore.deserializeAuthentication(JdbcTokenStore.java:405) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore$3.mapRow(JdbcTokenStore.java:198) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore$3.mapRow(JdbcTokenStore.java:196) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:679) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:712) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:790) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore.readAuthentication(JdbcTokenStore.java:195) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore.getAccessToken(JdbcTokenStore.java:129) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices.createAccessToken(DefaultTokenServices.java:84) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AbstractTokenGranter.getAccessToken(AbstractTokenGranter.java:72) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AbstractTokenGranter.grant(AbstractTokenGranter.java:67) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.CompositeTokenGranter.grant(CompositeTokenGranter.java:38) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer$4.grant(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer.java:583) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(TokenEndpoint.java:132) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:203) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Not allowed to deserialize com.example.oauth.user.domain.User
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.util.SerializationUtils$SaferObjectInputStream.resolveClass(SerializationUtils.java:125) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1886) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1772) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2355) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2249) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2355) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2249) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2087) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1594) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.util.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:62) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 103 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you please provide the stack trace?

Comment: Yes, I attached it. Then `NullpointerException` is handled but this stack trace is more important I think.

Comment: `User` needs to implement `Serializable`. This is rather basic.

Comment: @user207421 no, it isn't. The User already implements a interface that extends it.

Comment: @FabianoOliveira There is no evidence for that here. It clearly cannot be so. The stack trace doesn't lie.

Comment: Yes, there is evidence as it implements the `UserDetails` that extends it. At a first glance I thought the same as you, but looking to the stack trace you can see that the deserialize problem is in a Spring class. Looking at the code line it's clear that this problem is caused by this commit: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/commit/b214a25fdd8eae34c8ad803e7022fd17d1c63eb6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, apparently you ran into a bug of this version (`2.3.7.RELEASE`). Look at this issue:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1785

It happens on the exactly same line as yours and in the same version as yours. The bug is due an attempt to enhance security by deserializing only class on a whitelist in the Spring Security OAuth. It was a mistaken strategy though as it reflects on custom classes and it was reverted in the immediate next version (`2.3.8.RELEASE`).

Just upgrade your version of `spring-security-oauth` to `2.3.8.RELEASE` and your problem should be fixed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Changing version helped. I tried with `2.3.6.RELEASE` and `2.4.0.RELEASE`(released on 13th November - I was pretty sure during creation my project yesterday that `2.3.7.RELEASE` was the most recent version). They deprecated a lot in the newest version so I think the best way for me will be to downgrade and use `2.3.6.RELEASE`.

Comment: Im gonna go through your post history and upvote everything because I love you so much right now